# Key performance indicators to measure online brand image

Tags: analytics, strategy

A company is going to launch an event and a series of online related content that will be published on it's website and promoted online and offline to it's customers and leads. The event will last for two weeks and related content will be promoted during that period a few days later. The main content types will be news stories, interviews, blog posts, videos, and photos.

The purpose of this event and content is to improve brand image among it's customers.

**What are the best online Key Performance Indicators (KPI) that can be used to measure success of this initiative?**

- Results and conclusions must me presented a few days after the end of the event.
- The measurement tools will be Google Analytics, Facebook Insights, and Topsy.
- We don't want to create more than 5 or 6 KPI's, because a lot of KPI's produce results that are hard to communicate in a 10 minutes talk to people that are not web-savy .

Just to give you an example of what could be a possible KPI:

- Increase in the number of visits, where the visitor spends 25% more time on the site than the average of the last three months. *(Measured with Google Analytics)*

It looks like there's a lot of room for opinion on this question, but what I need is not opinions, but links to web pages. I'm looking for specific information about documented best marketing practices used today.

Answer (score 1):

[This article suggests the following goals and metrics for website brand](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/brand-measurement-analytics-metrics-branding-campaigns/):

- attract "prospects" and new customers -- *measured by number of new visitors*
- share your business value proposition -- *measured by visitor loyalty & visitor recency*
- impress people about your greatness and buy more -- *measured by conversion rate*
- whisper sweet nothings to drive offline action -- *measured by likelihood to recommend*
- break through the noise / make an introduction to your business -- *measured by "micro conversions"*
- destroy your competition -- *measured by share of search*
- emboss your brand into someone's skull -- *measured by rising searches*